# Classification of Brahman(ब्रह्मन्)

Tags: scripture, vedas, shiva, krishna, brahman

I was watching this program on TV and the person in there further classified the Ultimate Reality we call as Brahman / Par Brahman into three categories :

1. Nirãkãr Brahman (निराकार ब्रह्मन्)
2. Sãkãr Brahman (साकार ब्रह्मन्)
3. Tãrak Brahman (तारक ब्रह्मन्).

In one of the episodes of the program, the person also told that only Bhagwaan Shiva (भगवान शिव) and Bhagwaan Shri Krishna (भगवान श्री कृष्ण) are known as Tãrak Brahman (तारक ब्रह्मन्).

So my question is on the possible sources and the validity of all the above mentioned statements if present in any form, as per any scriptures or School of Thoughts?

Comment: Re: *I was watching this program on TV* Which programme?

Comment: I don't think that's really important to the context of question and answer, although, it was an Astrologer in a Astrology TV program.

Comment: TV writers are not valid sources for scripture.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this forum is not a forum to clarify TV writers or TV shows.

Comment: I'm exactly asking if there's some scripture and/ or traditional सम्प्रदाय based view on this, if any? The question itself is a conjecture to verify the validity or presence of (if any) of those "TV based views" in any existing part or entity of the Sanatan Dharma?!